# Adding Markdown JSX Language Injection to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown, jsx, remarkjs

## Short Summary

So, I’m trying to use [MDX](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx) in my project. It’s just MarkDown with some JSX (including ES6 imports) mingled in. I want to use IntelliJ to edit the files and get proper syntax highlighting for both the Markdown bits and the JSX bits.

I think I should be able to configure a [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) for this, but I’m a bit stalled trying to move forward. It looks like I’ll need to write the XML myself, since the language syntax I want is JSX, and the only target languages in the UI are xml, js, sql, and a few other common ones.

## What I've Tried

Looking at the source for the [Groovy injections](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/groovy/groovy-psi/src/resources/groovyInjections.xml) and the [Java injections](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/IntelliLang/java-support/resources/javaInjections.xml), I started to piece together what I'd need.

I [looked at the PSI Structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-psi-structure.html) of one of my sample MDX files (which I've told IntelliJ to treat as Markdown). I could see that my JSX tag was being registered as an HTML_TAG element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component name="LanguageInjectionConfiguration">
    <injection language="JSX" injector-id="markdown">
        <display-name>JSX in Markdown</display-name>
        <place><![CDATA[psiElement().withElementType(org.intellij.plugins.markdown.lang.MarkdownTokenTypes.HTML_TAG)]]></place>
    </injection>
</component>
```

IntelliJ failed to import that with a message saying, "No new entries have been imported". Then I looked at a sample export, and saw that I should use the `<LanguageInjectionConfiguration>` tag, so I tried:

```
<LanguageInjectionConfiguration>
    <injection language="JSX" injector-id="markdown" enabled="true">
        <display-name>JSX in Markdown</display-name>
        <place><![CDATA[psiElement().withElementType(org.intellij.plugins.markdown.lang.MarkdownTokenTypes.HTML_TAG)]]></place>
    </injection>
</LanguageInjectionConfiguration>
```

...but, I received the same error.

Looking at the IntelliJ logs, it displays this error:

> 2018-10-23 12:17:28,680 [3894254]   WARN - s.compiler.PatternCompilerImpl - JSX in Markdown: psiElement().withElementType(org.intellij.plugins.markdown.lang.MarkdownTokenTypes.HTML_TAG)
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 33(.): 'org.' method name start is invalid, '(' expected
>
> at com.intellij.patterns.compiler.PatternCompilerImpl.throwError(PatternCompilerImpl.java:293)
>
> ...long, long stack trace...
>
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

`MarkdownTokenTypes.HTML_TAG` is definitely of the `IElementType` required by [one of the `withElementType` method signatures](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/patterns/PsiElementPattern.java#L64).

## Conclusion

I fear that I'm over complicating this. Is there a good guide to writing custom language injection? It's not clear to me what the return type should be for the `place` tag, nor if I should favor using a pattern instead of a place.

Comment: For context, I know that IntelliJ support is an open issue for both the MDX project and JetBrains.
https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/119
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FWEB-32599

This seems like a low-hanging contribution, but I can't quite grasp how to craft a decent language injector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment on [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32599) there is a planned Addon coming that will enable "basic support" for MDX in JetBrains products:

[image: comment picture]

Not clear yet on what "basic MDX support" means, but it will be more than just syntax highlighting and word completion.  It will have "coding assistance" which I assume will be context actions, automatic imports, etc.  I asked for clarity on the thread and will update this answer if I hear anything more.